# Memcached in java

Tags: java, mysql, memcached

I am having web page which takes too much of time to load as its having a huge amount of data in mysql database.

I am using a java class file for connecting mysql database and executes a query.

I need have to add memcache .I have installed memcache .

And i had a code as follows

```
String[][] test=null;
MemcachedClient c=new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress("localhost",11211));
if (!"mykey1".equals("")&&"mykey1"!=null) {
    System.out.print(test[0][0]);
} else {
    System.out.print("Else");
    test=new Test(conn).getTestInfo(1,50);
    c.set(key, 3600, url);
    System.out.println("get"+c.get(key));
    Object myObject=c.get(key);
}
```

Where Test is another java class with db connection ...
If i run the above code it just executes else part and it goes on running the class file the build does not get stopped

Am really very new to memcache ,pls help me in doing memcache in java ......

Comment: mykey1 is key used for memcache ...i dont have clear view how to set memcache key

Comment: this is bizarre, what's mykey1 ? what is test? why is it set as a string array? what is Test class? what is key declared as?

Comment: can you post enough code please? this snippet is NOT helping why is mykey1 in double quotes?

Answer (score 4):

The code is so full of serious problems I don't even know where to begin.

1) This is the if statement

```
if(!"mykey1".equals("")&&"mykey1"!=null){
    System.out.print(test[0][0]);
} else {
```

The string m1key1 is never equals the empty string and is never equals to null, so what else than the else branch should be executed here?

Probably you mean a variable called mykey1 instead a string called "mykey1".

2) You would get an exception in line 4 every single time:

```
System.out.print(test[0][0]);
```

3) You only do a memcache lookup after you have set a value. This is usually not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Memcahced is a right way to go to offload your mysql. There a multiple ways of using it.
I recommend my resent opensource called **3levelmemcache** project as an example at **github** its Spring based abstraction, that hides all the details about Memcahced or Couchase or anything else and enables you to develop faster. It also has connection pools, and JVM 2nd level cache.